# Flask: how to add button that dynamically adds rows to a form when pressed

Tags: jquery, python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I haven't found anything that answers this question after looking around.

I have a simple form that contains 3 fields for String inputs initially, and then takes that input and flashes it (so I can see it).

What I would like to do is that when the user click a button it adds a similar line under the existing ones (so a fourth String input).

Is there a way to do that with python and flask-wtforms?

Basically, I want something like the input for Google Maps, where you can add a third, fourth, fifth, etc. location by pressing a '+' button.

EDIT: I realize that this can be done using Javascript, but I guess my actual question is how I can then access this data from within my Python files dealing with the views.

Comment: This is more of a javascript question than a flask question. You are updating the dom on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

```
class RowForm(Form):
  name = StringField("Name") # or whatever fields represent a row
  age = IntegerField("Age")

class MyForm(Form):
  add = SubmitField("Add")
  rows = FieldList(FormField(RowForm))

@app.post("/")
def index_post():
  form = MyForm(request.form)

  if form.add.data: # Add button was clicked
    form.rows.append_entry("") # can also pass in a dict

  return render_template("my-form.html", form=form)
```

Answer (score -1):

I recently did this outside of Flask. I did this with jquery. The below code appends a new input to the bottom of a div with an id of #example.

```
$("#addNewInput").click(function(){
  var newInput = $(document.createElement('input'))
   .attr("id", 'newInput');
  $("#example").append(newInput);
});
```

This works by giving a button an id of #addNewInput such as:

```
<button type="button" id="addNewInput">Add Input</button>
```

Comment: I tried something like this, but how do I access the input data within my Python file that does stuff with the data?

Right now, my views.py file initiates a custom Form object and hands that to the html template (using render_template()). When the submit button is pressed, I check validate_on_submit() on the Form object, and then use the form data. But since adding a new input does not add a new attribute to the Form() object, I can't access that data.

Comment: should be able to retrieve values like: `request.args.get('age')`